# Are methods returning references to class members cache friendly?

Tags: c++, caching

It is a *common practice* to create "getter" functions in classes returning the reference to the parameter to be modified. My question is if this is a cache-friendly practice, because I suspect that every time the "getter" method is called the cache is flushed away to jump to that method.

Could anyone tell me if this is true or give me some directions? Here is an example:

```
class X
{
  public:
    int& getA() { return a; }
    int& getB() { return b; }
  private:
    int a, b;
};

int main()
{
  X x;           // cache should contain x data
  x.getA() = 0u; // cache destroyed because of calling getA()?
  x.getB() = 1u; // cache destroyed again because of calling getB()?
}
```

Comment: what do you mean the cache is flushed away? you mean the instruction cache?

Comment: Mostly it won't matter, and certainly won't matter for a simple case like you describe (only one instance of a class with members of `int` type, the getters inlined, simple operations). The choice of algorithms to act on your objects and their data will have a more significant impact on "cache friendliness" than whether your getter functions return references or by value.  I suggest reading up on the concept of "premature optimisation" (worrying about the impact that minor coding changes have on performance before doing any measurements to determine *if* there is a performance concern).

Comment: In that example, this will *effectively* be exactly as cache friendly as making the member public and accessing it directly, since it's pretty much a guarantee the compiler will perform that optimization. There's no telling that'll still be the case in all scenarios though.

Comment: Learn about _inlining_. A compiler will almost surely optimize that getter function call away, if it can see its definition (which is your case).

Comment: @PYA Yes, instruction cache.
@Peter This is only a simple example, my code contains many more parameters with different types, not only `int`. Thanks for your the "premature optimization" hint.
@Frank Thanks!
@DanielLangr Thanks!

If the "getter" itself is not important, will the order affect cache? For example, if I switch around them like: `x.getB() = 1u; x.getA() = 0u; `

Comment: @Victor Your compiler is already taking all of that into account. It will reorder your code around not only to make best use of the instruction cache, but also to minimize pipeline stalls and a myriad of other concerns. The odds of you beating the compiler at this game is minimal. When people talk about cache-friendly code being important, it's the the data cache they are referring to, not the instruction cache, and even then, this only really applies to tight inner loops, not code in general.